# Mapbox online map on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I'm totally new to mapbox API on iOS , i follow the instruction on there site and make a custom map with marker -
[My Map Online Link](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/scorpioo.map-a6l64b06/page.html#19.00/31.40656/34.32382)
- and i add the binary framework and it load with the map without any marker

```
#import <MapBox/MapBox.h>

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
RMMapView *map =[[RMMapBoxSource alloc]initWithMapID:@"scorpioo.map-a6l64b06"];
RMMapView *mapV = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds andTilesource:map];
}
```

so anyone can tell me why it not shown ? or know how can i show the marker that i put on the online map on my ios ?

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: As i said , no marker is shown on the map on iOS , but it shown on the Site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using this method of `RMMapBoxSource`:

http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/#//api/name/initWithMapID:enablingDataOnMapView:

Create your `RMMapView` first, then create your `RMMapBoxSource`, pass the map view as the second argument. This will pull down server-side markers and automatically display them.

Here is an example project which shows this:

https://github.com/mapbox/weekend-picks-template-ios

The technology here is called *simplestyle*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines in the above code. So that you can get the desired marker :

`RMPointAnnotation *annotation = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:map coordinate:MENTION_COORDINATES_HERE andTitle:@"Hello, world!"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];`

Complete Example :

```
RMMapBoxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"examples.map-z2effxa8"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    RMPointAnnotation *annotation = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView 
                                                                    coordinate:mapView.centerCoordinate 
                                                                      andTitle:@"Hello, world!"];

    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this code is to add an annotation from the code , but i need to design map on the flow so that every update i made is shown to all Clint without pushing an update to the app on the store

Comment: @Scorpioo.4 I don't think, that would be possible. Rest you can check out the official documentation of MapBox.

Comment: i think it possible , because the foursquare is hosted on this site and worked perfectly